# Is there a way to list what CSI drivers are installed in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Looking for something like `kubectl get drivers` but there doesn't appear to be a way to list them.

Comment: Hi @alex, could you please post your edit as an answer for more visibility?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
kubectl get csidriver
```

Is the command what I was looking for!

There is related [documentation](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/csi-driver-object.html) about that.